# How to check if a struct contains unexported fields in Golang?

Tags: go

Example:

I have a struct,

```
 type Person struct {
        Name string
        DOB string
        age int
    }

func detectUnexportedInStruct(i interface{}) bool {
         // if `i` contains unexported fields return true
         // else return false
    }
    
func main() {
    fmt.Println(detectUnexportedInStruct(Person{Name: "", DOB: ""}))
}
```

I would want `true` to be printed because Person contains an unexported field `age`.

How can I build my `detectUnexportedInStruct()` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package:

```golang
func detectUnexportedInStruct(i interface{}) bool {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(i)
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        if !rt.Field(i).IsExported() {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/f_JVLWYavjm

Comment: Thanks. This works absolutely fine if structs don't contain any field which is of another struct type.

Another question on what if I have nested structs with unexported fields?

Comment: You can use recursion, for that you can re-write the function so that it accepts `reflect.Type` as its argument. https://play.golang.org/p/sH4CRh_W6TQ